# Find and replace with regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to replace a bunch of function calls using regular expressions but can't seem to be getting it right. This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
GetPetDog();
GetPetCat();
GetPetBird();
```

I want to change to:

```
GetPet<Animal_Dog>();
GetPet<Animal_Cat>();
GetPet<Animal_Bird>();
```

Comment: And why are you not just finding `GetPetDog` and replace it with `GetPet<Animal_Dog>` ?

Comment: The search-replace mechanism in VS is pretty good, and can handle regular expressions. What have you tried so far? How did it fail?

Comment: The reason I don't want to use GetPetDog is because I've got over 20 pet types. I'm looking for something that can work generically for all the different types

Comment: I've tried a bunch of different ones, e.g. GetPet(.*), but that seems to be picking up the whole line. So if I have a call where it says e.g. GetPetDog().GiveFood(), it matches the whole line. So it replaces with GetPet<Animal_Dog().GiveFood()>(); I can't seem to get it to stop before the first bracket after Dog.

Answer (score 8):

Use below regex:

```
(GetPet)([^(]*) with subsitution \1<Animal_\2>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX8qU1/2)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Also, great link, I'll definitely use that in the future!

Comment: Accept the answer so that it may help to others also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex and code for that:

```
std::string ss ("GetPetDog();");
static const std::regex ee ("GetPet([^()]*)");
std::string result;
result = regex_replace(ss, ee, "GetPet<Animal_$1>");
std::cout << result << endl;
```

**Regex**:

- `GetPet` - Matches `GetPet` literally (we need no capturing group here)
- `([^()]*)` - A capturing group to match any characters other than `(` or `)` 0 or more times (`*`)

Output:

[image]